# Change the type of the custom button from props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created a custom button component in React and I'm unable to change it's type. I tried to change the type to `String` but typescript gives me an error that it's not assignable. Any help would be appreciated.

```ts
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  className: string;
  onClick: () => void;
  type?: string;   ---> I tried making this string 
}

const STYLES = ["bg-gradient-to-r from from-gold to to-gold-dark","bg-gradient-to-r from from-primary to to-primary-dark"];
const BUTTONTYPE = ["submit","reset"];

//created a array to change type according to input
const CustomButton = (props: Props) => {
  const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(props.className)
    ? props.className
    : "NULL";

  const checkButtonType = BUTTONTYPE.includes(props.type) ? props.type : "button";  
  return (
//gives problem here regarding the type
    <button type={`${checkButtonType}`} className={`w-48 h-12  rounded-xl shadow-lg ${checkButtonStyle}`} onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default CustomButton;
```

Typescript error:

```plaintext
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"submit" | "reset" | "button" | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: What does typescript compiler say?

Comment: It gives me the warning```Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"submit" | "reset" | "button" | undefined'.ts(2322)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update type like this:

```
type?: "submit" | "reset" | "button";
```

Comment: Thank you Viet, I was thinking that we need to define the data type Since we are defining the type in the Interface, I should look into the error message more, Thanks again Sachin

Answer (score 6):

Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"submit" | "reset" | "button" | undefined'.

The error speaks for itself, your **checkButtonType** is type string and button type only accept these types:

"submit" | "reset" | "button" | undefined

You will need to update your type to:

```
type?: 'submit' | 'reset' | 'button';
```

**And the button element to:**

```
<button
  type={checkButtonType}
  className={`w-48 h-12  rounded-xl shadow-lg ${checkButtonStyle}`}
  onClick={props.onClick}
>
  {props.children}
</button>
```

Because **{`${checkButtonType}`}** always result in a string which is not matched with any of the types: "submit" | "reset" | "button" | undefined

Comment: Thank you Ryan Le, I was thinking to add the data type into the Interface that I have created and Since we manually enter the value It should always be a string, I need to read the error message more clearly and understand the error from It. Thanks again, Sachin